# AC Condensor Motor Wiring

Tags: hvac, motor

I am replacing the AC condenser motor , the original had 3 wires, black, purple and brown, in the dual capacitor the brown is to the fan and purple to the common.

My replacement motor has 2 black and 1 brown and 1 brown with white. I am kind of confused if i connect one black to common or leave one black and brown with white alone. Any input is appreciated in the capacitor, thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: Depending where you live the wire color would have different meaning.

Comment: check the label on each of the motors for a connection diagram

Comment: I uploaded an image of wiring to new motor

Answer (score 1):

The wiring diagram on the motor pictured calls for a capacitor (7.5 µF and 370 VAC rated) between brown and brown/white.

Line goes to black (so line 1 and line 2 if 240V, or line and neutral if 120V) with both blacks being used to connect to the line in either case.

Comment: So both black wires from the motor will connect to black line wire from contactor or both black wires are going straight to contactor. The reason I ask is the contactor is on one side of the unit and a wire was ran as an extension to the side where the motor wires extended from motor wire tube near dual capacitor. I hope it make sense

Comment: Your hope is not borne out by the lack of a picture of that, so that we can see what you see. They do not both connect to the SAME wire - they connect to both sides of the line supply, whether that be two hots (240V) or hot and neutral (120V) one motor black to each side of the line.

Comment: I’ll try to provide some pictures soon, thank you for the feedback and patience, I appreciate it.

Comment: Uploaded a picture with wiring info

Comment: Update, I ordered an OEM replacement motor and everything is all good.